# Dynamic Query not working along with an variable

Tags: sql-server-2008

```
declare  @SQL  varchar(2000)
declare @Total int 

SET @SQL = 'Select'+@Total+'= SUM(isnull(Points,0)) as Pointsvalue  From  Offer'

exec(@SQL)  

select @Total
```

I am trying to do like this but always the result shows me as empty. But when I run the query directly it gives an result of 120

Where I am going wrong? Please let me know

Thanks

prince

Comment: Why does this need to be a dynamic query?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to run this as a dynamic query, try like this:

```
declare @SQL nvarchar(2000), @Total int 

SET @SQL = N'Select @Total = SUM(isnull(Points,0)) as Pointsvalue  From  Offer'
exec sp_executesql @SQL, N'@Total int output', @Total = @Total output

select @Total
```

(see [sp_executesql (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188001.aspx))

However, it looks like you don't have a really dynamic query there.
So, as msmucker0527 pointed out you could simply run:

```
declare @Total int 

Select @Total = SUM(isnull(Points,0)) as Pointsvalue  From  Offer

select @Total
```

Answer (score 1):

What you were trying to do is (I think)

```
SET @SQL = 'Select @Total = SUM(isnull(Points,0)) as Pointsvalue  From  Offer'
```

However that will tell you off because @Total is not in scope (The query in an Exec has it's own)

There again you don't need to do the exec if you want the above...

So I'm a bit confused on what you were trying to achieve

A tip

When you write a query using exec(String). 
Comment out the exec, and replace it with Print @SQL, see waht it's going to try and do.